# How to generate python exe of a python script including other python scripts

Tags: python, py2exe

I am trying to generate an exe for the python script "cnss_image_loader.py" which imports other python scripts in the same folder(see below),now I try to generate "cnss_image_loader.exe" using command `python setup.py py2exe`(see output below) and running into below errors,not sure if they are real issue or not but when running the generated exe throws the errors shown below

QUESTION:

1.Can I not use py2exe to generate an executable?

2.***Can anyone exactly point to what I am missing and provide guidance to generate the exe?***

3.Is there a better way to generate a python executable?

**ERROR:-**

```
C:\Dropbox\py2exe\dist>cnss_image_loader.exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cnss_image_loader.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "android_dl.pyc", line 2, in <module>
  File "pip\__init__.pyc", line 14, in <module>
  File "pip\utils\__init__.pyc", line 22, in <module>
  File "pip\compat\__init__.pyc", line 26, in <module>
ImportError: No module named ipaddr
```

**Directory structure:-**
[image: py2exe]

cnss_image_loader.py

```
from android_dl import *
from alpaca import *
```

**setup.py**

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe 
setup(console=['cnss_image_loader.py'])
```

**python setup.py py2exe**

```
The following modules appear to be missing
['Carbon', 'Carbon.Files', 'ElementC14N', 'OpenSSL.SSL', 'Pyrex.Distutils.build_ext', '_frozen_importlib', '_imp', '_manylinux', '_posixsubprocess', '_scproxy', '_sysconfigdata', 'backports.ssl_match_hostname', 'builtins', 'certifi', 'charade.universaldetector', 'chardet', 'chardet.universaldetector', 'configparser', 'datrie', 'genshi.core', 'html', 'html.entities', 'html.parser', 'http', 'http.client', 'http.cookies', 'importlib.machinery', 'importlib.util', 'ipaddr', 'ipaddress', 'java', 'lxml', 'lxml.etree', 'lzma', 'ndg.httpsclient.ssl_peer_verification', 'ndg.httpsclient.subj_alt_name', 'ordereddict', 'packages.six.moves', 'packages.ssl_match_hostname.CertificateError', 'packages.ssl_match_hostname.match_hostname', 'packages.urllib3.util.Timeout', 'packages.urllib3.util.parse_url', 'pip._vendor.six.moves.urllib', 'pyasn1.codec.der', 'pyasn1.type', 'queue', 'redis', 'reprlib', 'serial', 'serial.tools.list_ports', 'serializer.serialize', 'simplejson', 'sitecustomize', 'socks', 'tree
builders.getTreeBuilder', 'treewalkers.getTreeWalker', 'trie.Trie', 'urllib.error', 'urllib.parse', 'urllib.request', 'urllib3', 'urllib3.packages.backports.makefile', 'usercustomize', 'xmlrpc.client']

*** binary dependencies ***
Your executable(s) also depend on these dlls which are not included,
you may or may not need to distribute them.

Make sure you have the license if you distribute any of them, and
make sure you don't distribute files belonging to the operating system.

   OLEAUT32.dll - C:\WINDOWS\system32\OLEAUT32.dll
   USER32.dll - C:\WINDOWS\system32\USER32.dll
   IMM32.dll - C:\WINDOWS\system32\IMM32.dll
   SHELL32.dll - C:\WINDOWS\system32\SHELL32.dll
   ole32.dll - C:\WINDOWS\system32\ole32.dll
   COMDLG32.dll - C:\WINDOWS\system32\COMDLG32.dll
   COMCTL32.dll - C:\WINDOWS\system32\COMCTL32.dll
   ADVAPI32.dll - C:\WINDOWS\system32\ADVAPI32.dll
   NETAPI32.dll - C:\WINDOWS\system32\NETAPI32.dll
   WS2_32.dll - C:\WINDOWS\system32\WS2_32.dll
   GDI32.dll - C:\WINDOWS\system32\GDI32.dll
   VERSION.dll - C:\WINDOWS\system32\VERSION.dll
   KERNEL32.dll - C:\WINDOWS\system32\KERNEL32.dll
   ntdll.dll - C:\WINDOWS\system32\ntdll.dll
```

Comment: BTW,this method works if the python script doesnt include other python scripts

Answer (score 0):

Something I have been using personally is pyinstaller. You can install it for python using the following command on cmd:

```
pip install pyinstaller
```

After installing you can use it in the following way:

```
python -m pyinstaller main.py
```

where main.py is your python module. You can also provide an icon file for your application using the `--icon` option as follows

```
python -m pyinstaller --icon=hi.ico main.py
```

You can also create a standalone application using the `--onefile` option as follows:

```
python -m pyinstaller --onefile main.py
```

You can find more info on their website https://www.pyinstaller.org or on their manual at https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

Comment: Kamil it will be great if you provide a link to where more details can be gotten about pyinstaller and using it. Maybe a blog post, the packages documentation page etc.

Comment: @DejiS I recommend reading their manual (https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) as it is pretty descriptive on how to use it. Sorry for the late reply.

Comment: No worries. Happy you edited your answer to provide the links to their website and documentation. This should greatly ease understanding your answer Thanks!